# How do I get Nearby Messages to publish / receive from second activity?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have got Nearby Messages apparently working fine exchanging messages happily between IOS and Android, but my Android app has multiple Activities. Once I switched to the second Activity the messages stop.

I have stripped out all the code in the Android app except for the line Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(listener).

I then have a button to switch to a new instance of the same Activity. This works (messages are received from an IOS App that is just sending messages every 15 seconds) as a first Activity, but then fails (no messages received) once I click on the button and it starts itself.

Note that the onSuccessListner callback is triggered (the onFailureListener isn't).  It thinks it is registered, but just doesn't get any messages.

I also did this with 2 copies of Activity with the same code, just to check that it wasn't because it was the same Activity class that it was failing.  Still failed.

I took the Google sample App.  This still uses the deprecated GooglaApiClient.  It still gives the same result though.

I did spot that if the user has to take an action to enable the messages it works (as in the sample where the user has to switch messages on).  I therefore tried adding a delay.  A delay of 400 milliseconds means on my device that it works.  300 milliseconds and it still fails.

So I seem to have 2 choices.  Add a spurious 1 second delay before enabling messages, or convert my App to use Fragments and a single Activity (I tried using the Application context and contrary to some documentation I found it tells me it must be an Activity Context).  Neither are satisfactory workarounds, so am hoping that I have done something stupid.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->  // Switch to self.
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)  
    }
    mMessageListener = object : MessageListener() {
        override public fun onFound(message: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found message: " + String(message.content))  //Triggered ok until Activity switch
        }
    }
}
override public fun onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiScope.launch {// Using coroutines as a simple means of adding a delay.  It also fails with no coroutine (and no delay)
        delay(300)   // This fails - but a value of 400 means that messages are received
        Nearby.getMessagesClient(this@MainActivity2).subscribe(mMessageListener)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "Success")  // Always triggered
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed " + it)  // Never triggered
            }
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).unsubscribe(mMessageListener)
    super.onStop();
}
```

This is the code I am currently using, but as commented above it also fails with the old API, with Java, with no coroutines, etc.  The Logcat is identical in the 300 or 400 ms cases.

Comment: If you want to receive messages and be able to switch activities or even close your app and still receive messages it may be worth it to look into services.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: The Nearby Messages API documentation says that you can only do background messages with BLE (it doesn't work with the ultrasonic option). I don't need this to work in background - just need the ability to communicate on various different screens.